# User mode FileSystem in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I need to implement sqlite VFS above raw device. This involves almost writing your own user mode filesystem.

I was wondering if there is such filesystem them let me do basic operation on raw devices without mounting the device?

Comment: You probably should look into the source code of `fuse` ( http://fuse.sourceforge.net/ )

Comment: FUSE involves a kernel module. I'm looking for a pure user mode filesystem.